# IIS 7.5 + CGI + SSL - How to increase the upload limit?

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, cgi

I'm hitting a really annoying problem with IIS 7. I've setup my web.config by the books as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <handlers>
            <add name="Python" path="*.cgi" verb="*" modules="CgiModule" scriptProcessor="C:\Python27\python.exe -u &quot;%s&quot;" resourceType="Unspecified" requireAccess="Script" />
        </handlers>
        <security>
            <requestFiltering>
                <!-- maxAllowedContentLength is in bytes (B)  -->
                <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="1073741824" /> <!-- 1GB -->
            </requestFiltering>
        </security>
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <rule name="rewrite to hgwebdir" patternSyntax="Wildcard">
                    <match url="*" />
                    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
                        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Rewrite" url="hgweb.cgi/{R:1}" />
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
    <system.web>
        <!-- maxRequestLength is in kilobytes (KB)  -->
        <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="1048576" /> <!-- 1GB -->
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

When I POST to the CGI script (it's hgweb for Mercurial via Python) via HTTP everything is fine - no problems whatsoever.

However, when I POST to the script via HTTPS (SSL) I'm still capped at the default upload limit of 30MB. This doesn't make any sense to me. What is going on?!

Comment: Follow this question in the IIS forums as well: http://forums.iis.net/t/1197751.aspx/2/10?p=True&t=635036050464908385

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an incompatibility in the SSL module of Python 2.7.3+.

Bug documented here on the TortoiseHg site, but it applies to all platforms pushing into IIS over HTTPS.

https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/2593/cant-push-over-30mb-to-iis-via-https

There are more details in my related StackOverflow post about this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16486104/97964